# Take value from list and use it as index

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a matrix (A) like this (the names of row and column are identification codes (ID):

```
     1   3  10  38  46
 1   0 0.4   0   0   0
 3   0   0   0   0   0
10   0   0 0.9 0.8   0
38   0   0   0   0   0
46   0 0.1   0   0   0
```

And another matrix (B) like this:

```
               a            b            c
1   2.676651e-04 4.404911e-06 9.604227e-06
3   6.073389e-10 3.273222e-05 3.360321e-04
10  4.156392e-08 1.269607e-06 7.509217e-06
38  4.200699e-08 3.227431e-02 8.286920e-11
46  9.352353e-05 3.318948e-20 8.694981e-06
```

I would like to take the index of the elements of the A matrix >0, therefore I  used this command:

```
temp <- apply(A,1, FUN=function(x) which(x>0))
```

it returned a list with the correct index of the elements >0.

After that I would like to multiply the element of the matrix B using the index. In particular, I would like to do something like these for each row:

```
1: 6.073389e-10*3.273222e-05*3.360321e-04
```

I have used the information of the matrix A  (in the second column of the first row I have a value >0) as index to take the element in the matrix B for the first row.

For the second row, I obtained 0 because there aren't element in A[2,]>0

For the third row, I would like to obtain something like the first row, but I should sum the two products

```
10: 4.156392e-08*1.269607e-06*7.509217e-06  +4.200699e-08*3.227431e-02*8.286920e-11
```

I have tried to unlist the list but in this way I obtained a vector losing the corresponding between the ID

Comment: Maybe you want `which(A>0, arr.ind=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
A <-
  matrix(
    c(0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0),
    nrow = 5,
    ncol = 5,
    byrow = T
  )
B <-
  matrix(
    c(
      2.676651e-04, 4.404911e-06, 9.604227e-06,
      6.073389e-10, 3.273222e-05, 3.360321e-04,
      4.156392e-08, 1.269607e-06, 7.509217e-06,
      4.200699e-08, 3.227431e-02, 8.286920e-11,
      9.352353e-05, 3.318948e-20, 8.694981e-06
    ),
    nrow = 5,
    ncol = 3,
    byrow = T
  )

idx<-which(A>0, arr.ind = T)

result <- 0;
for (i in 1:nrow(idx)) {
  cat(A[idx[i,1],idx[i,2]], sep="\n")
  cat(B[idx[i,2], ], sep="\n")
  result = result + sum(A[idx[i,1],idx[i,2]] * B[idx[i,2],])
}
cat("result=")
cat(result)
```